# How to have one div inside another div

Tags: html, css, canvasjs

Hi I am using canvasjs for making a chart. It is very simple to make a particular chart but here is the problem I want to have two different charts such that a pie chart would be inside of a doughnut chart.

I am not able to make one other inside. I have used the

```
display : inline-block
```

for the `two div id` but no effect. Could someone please suggest me how we can make that happen.

This is my code-

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script> 
<link type='text/css' rel="stylesheet" href='style.css' />
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        title:{
            text: "My First Chart in CanvasJS"              
        },
        data: [              
        {
            // Change type to "doughnut", "line", "splineArea", etc.
            type: "doughnut",
            dataPoints: [
                { label: "apple",  y: 10  },
                { label: "orange", y: 15  },
                { label: "banana", y: 25  },
                { label: "mango",  y: 30  },
                { label: "grape",  y: 28  }
            ]
        }
        ]
    });
    chart.render();
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainerpie", {
        data: [              
        {
            // Change type to "doughnut", "line", "splineArea", etc.
            type: "pie",
            dataPoints: [
                { label: "apple",  y: 10  },
                { label: "orange", y: 15  },
                { label: "banana", y: 25  },
                { label: "mango",  y: 30  },
                { label: "grape",  y: 28  }
            ]
        }
        ]
    });
    chart.render();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<div id="chartContainerpie" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;></div>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS only contains the line for display block.

[image: I want something like this]

Comment: `<div id="chartContainerpie" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;></div>` is missing closing `"` on style attribute - don't think this is the answer but it won't help

Comment: And do you have any live demo? To check how its looking now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the perfect answer but it will point you in right direction:

The idea is to change the background color of canvas to transparent and overlap the two canvas using `position` css

**CSS**

```
#chartContainerpie{
  position: absolute;
  top: 130px;
  left: 0px;
}
#chartContainer{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  title: {
    text: "My First Chart in CanvasJS"
  },
  backgroundColor: "transparent",
  data: [{
    // Change type to "doughnut", "line", "splineArea", etc.
    type: "doughnut",
    dataPoints: [{
      label: "apple",
      y: 10
    }, {
      label: "orange",
      y: 15
    }, {
      label: "banana",
      y: 25
    }, {
      label: "mango",
      y: 30
    }, {
      label: "grape",
      y: 28
    }]
  }]
});
chart.render();
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainerpie", {
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
  data: [{
    // Change type to "doughnut", "line", "splineArea", etc.
    indexLabelPlacement: "inside",
    indexLabelFontColor: "white",
    indexLabelFontSize: "14px",
    type: "pie",
    dataPoints: [{
      label: "apple",
      y: 10
    }, {
      label: "orange",
      y: 15
    }, {
      label: "banana",
      y: 25
    }, {
      label: "mango",
      y: 30
    }, {
      label: "grape",
      y: 28
    }]
  }]
});
chart.render();
```

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/egmjtfyu/)

Comment: I am having a similar problem in this question could you please help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41607486/make-pie-chart-bigger-without-affecting-doughnut-chart/41607600?noredirect=1#comment70417678_41607600