# Making a pie chart bigger without affecting the doughnut chart

Tags: html, css, canvasjs

I am making a pie chart and doughnut chart using `canvasjs`.

I have the pie chart inside a doughnut chart. I am not that good when it comes to CSS. Here the pie chart is at the center, but still it is very small. I don't know how to make it bigger as it is messing up the pie chart if I am attempt to make it bigger.

Is there any way the pie chart can be made bigger so there would not be much space between pie chart and the doughnut chart.

I am posting a picture of my result here.
[image: Please see the image]

I am using these properties:

**for doughnut**

```
 width="100%" height="250px" top="0px" position="absolute" backgroundColor="transparent" uniqueID ="doughnut"
```

**for pie chart**

```
width="78px" height="100px" top="75px" position="absolute" left="560px"  backgroundColor="transparent" uniqueID=”pie”
```

EDIT : If I increase height and width of pie chart which results in -

Why white space is coming when I have set background color to transparent??

This is my pie chart properties-

```
                   type: "pie",
                   backgroundColor: "transparent",
                   indexLabelFontColor: "white",
                   indexLabelFontSize: "14px",
                   markerType: "circle",
                   radius : "100%",
                   innerRadius :"200px",
```

I want something like this-
[image: Want something like this]

Answer (score 1):

You are probably getting smaller pie chart because of the height and the width of the container. Since, the height and the width of container is used by CanvasJS charts in order to determine the height of chart.

```
width="78px" height="100px" top="75px" position="absolute" left="560px"  backgroundColor="transparent" uniqueID=”pie”
```

Try varying height and width in above given statement to see the changes and obtain proper size of pie chart as per your requirement.
You should also vary **top** and **left** in proportion to *height* and *width* of the container containing pie chart.

Comment: I already tried that but because of increase height and width its div is overlapping the inner circle of doughnut which  in results add some white space on the doughnut...although I have set background color as transparent..see my edited pic

Comment: Set backgroundColor to *transparent* in chart instead of changing it in div. Take a look at this link: http://jsfiddle.net/m95jjzx5/2/

Comment: Are you still getting that white space on doughnut?

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://jsfiddle.net/m95jjzx5/4/ There is no white background for pie chart and it is responsive as well.

Comment: And backgroundColor shouldn't be inside data. It should be directly kept inside chart options.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133055/discussion-between-beevk-and-shv22).

Answer (score 0):

Try using this layout:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="doughnut"></div>
  <div class="pie"></div>
</div>
```

And apply this CSS:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.doughnut, .pie {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: no it is not working now only pie chart is coming up]

Comment: Opps, have a type, try again.

Comment: but what did you change?

Comment: Changed `position: absolute:` to `position: absolute;`

Comment: Okay, could you post your html and CSS?

Comment: I already posted it in the question which I was using...and the the one you gave...it makes pie chart bigger surely but hide the doughnut chart

Answer (score 0):

I am able to figure out how to do this-

I am using these property

```
#parent {
  position: relative;
}

#doughnutContainer, #pieContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
#doughnutContainer {
  width:800px;
  height:250px;
}
#pieContainer {
  transform: translate(-50%, 28%);
  width:200px; 
  height:160px;
}
```

Comment: @VishwasR I edited the question please check I want image something like this

Comment: @shv22 Please don't keep on editing the same question as this might confuse other users.

Comment: @Beevk I am just updating question for the canvasjs forum guys as I not able to upload pics there and also I already answered my question...